# Track entity updates (by who and when)

Tags: mysql

I need some advice on how to store information about who created/updated an "entity". I keep going back and forth between Option1, 2 and 3 (see below):

### Background

- This is a legacy system and there are currently two types of users: e.g. employees and customers.
- The users have different userId (saved in different tables...)
- The employee key is a char of 50 characters and the customerId is a char of 30 characters.
- Also, the employee is working at an office (might be several), so we want to track from which office the update/insert came from
- The office key is a char of 50 characters.
- The database is quite large: 200+ tables

### Option 1

Store the "meta data" together with the entity.

```
Create table order(
    orderId int not null primary key auto_increment
    ...
    insertedByEmployee CHAR(50),
    insertedFromOffice CHAR(50),
    insertedByCustumer CHAR(30),
    insertedDate dateTime,
    updatedByEmployee CHAR(50),
    updatedFromOffice CHAR(50),
    updatedByCustomer CHAR(30),
    updatedDate timestamp
);
```

The primary advantage of this method is that it is straight forward fo find the updated field. The downside is that there are redundant columns.

### Option 2

In this scenario I've moved the "meta data" to a separate table. Adds the possibility to have history. Don't know how relevant history is in this case though.

```
Create table order(
    orderId int not null primary key auto_increment
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE order_meta (
    order_metaId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orderId INT,
    customerId CHAR(30),
    employeeId CHAR(50),
    officeId CHAR(50),
    action ENUM('create','update'),
    dateTime` TIMESTAMP
);
```

What I like about this approach is that some redundancy is removed. Also, if we want to track "reads" we could simply updated the "action" column. This design makes it harder to find the last updated record though. Perhaps there should be updatedDate in the entity table. Also, I'm going to need one meta-table per entity, which i really don't like.

### Option 3

Instead of using multiple columns for user id:s, create a "virtual user" and assign an id which will be used regardless of type.

A generic table (meta) is used to track changes to all entities. The downside is that this table might get used A LOT and makes querying for changes more cumbersome. I'm worried it might become a bottleneck.

This design doesn't require creating a separate table for each entity. Finding the actual user performing the update/insert is even more complicated than the other options. On the other hand I think this one might scale better.

Pseudo code (vuserId currently doesn't exist):

```
Create table order(
    orderId int not null primary key auto_increment,
    updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE virtual_user(
    vuserId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT),
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE customer(
    vuserId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customerId CHAR(30),
    ...
);

CREATE table employee(
    vuserId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    employeeId char(50)
    ...
);
    
CREATE TABLE meta (
  metaId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  entityName VARCHAR(30),
  entityId VARCHAR(50),
  vuserId INT,
  officeId CHAR(50),
  action ENUM('create','update'),
  dateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Why not have a table System_user with a  User_type reference table with entries (C, E). Please don't use ENUM's - see [here](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) for why. They can perform a (ref_table) User_action (C, U, D) from an Action_location (1... n - also a reference to a Location table). Obviously, I don't know the (undoubtedly complex) details of your system, but I'm a big believer in KISS and this seems (stress on **seems**) simple to me. Perhaps also a Cust_detail and Emp_detail linked to the System_user PK?

Comment: p.s. it seems that what I have said is closest to your solution 3. +1 by the way for the clear, well formatted question (and the deadly handle! :-))

Comment: Do you also want to track what the update was? i.e. "Changed price from x to y"? Also, if there are more updates, do you want to track all, or only the last one? Answering these will affect the design.

Comment: At this point, I don't need to track _what_ was updated, only _who_ did an update. But you do have a point, and the more I think about it, tracking what was updated seem to be the obvious next step in the future.

Comment: @Vérace: I'm a strong believer in KISS myself. With that said, I find it easier said than done at times. You don't want to end up with something too simple :) Thanks for the link to the article. I sure didn't know there are 8 reasons ENUMs are evil :D I'll read that one in detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** is a no; this level of un-normalized data will mean many extra data pages occupying more space on disk, more data pages having to be read/written on operations, ...

Between **Option 2** and **Option 3** I'd go with something closer to **Option 3** - In here you will save many bytes related to users (an `Int` goes for 4 bytes instead of the 30/50 of the `Chars`). This will save you again considerable disk space (considering users appear more than once) and get you smaller indexes which will mean better performance.

Now, on **Option 3**, I might be missing something for I don't understand what entityName and entityId stand for. If this is user information, it will better stay on the `virtual_user` table so you won't get this info repeated in every meta. Also, on the `meta` table I'd keep the `orderId`, it will allow you proper and fast joining of the `meta` and `order` tables, providing adequate indexing is present. I don't know the specifics of your requirements but consider if the `updated` column is necessary on the `Order` table or if for displaying the desired info on the application you'll be joining with the latest registry from the `meta` table all of the time.

If you want to keep track of order history, depending on requirements you might want to consider having a separate table (`orderHistory` or 'orderChanges'), or partitioning the `order` table. Now, especially for this last case, the `order` table could have a composite key composed by `(orderId, metaId)`, making it Unique and a candidate index for joining with the `meta` table.

-- After the explaining comment:
The `meta` table will be the most heavily used one, so keep everything as short as possible on this one:

1. Clustered index on `metaId`
2. Add a table `entityTypes` which relates `entityName CHAR` to `entityType int`. This will also get you a nice list of entities for anyone new looking at the database to know which entities relate to meta
3. Try having `entityId` as `int` for all entities (If you can't change/add column to the existing tables, add an intermediary table) - This will reduce the field to 4bytes and allow one single data type for all entities.
4. Add an index to `meta` table on `entityType` (now int) and `entityId` (now int). Your rows on this heavily used table are now so short you should be doing everything lightning fast.

Comment: I didn't thoroughly explain _entityName_ and _entityId_, my apologies. The example merely focused on one entity: order. We have lots more "entities" in our database, such as notes, documents etc (merely examples). The idea was that the entity name and the corresponding id will be inserted into entityName and entityId. Like entityName="note" and entityId=3, or entityName="order" and entityId=55.  My concern about this design is "joining" the tables. Since meta contains information about lots of entities which might have the same key (numeric in some cases, strings in other).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is redundant, option 2 & 3 will much access the single table so it would slow the insert/update due to locking. I think You can break the option 1 into 2 tables, one for insert and other for update. So at least new entity would created fast and update might be little slow as compared to it.

```
Create table order(
    orderId int not null primary key auto_increment
    ...
    created_id int,
    updated_id int
 );

 Create table created(
    created_id int primary key auto_increment,
    insertedByEmployee CHAR(50),
    insertedFromOffice CHAR(50),
    insertedByCustumer CHAR(30),
    insertedDate dateTime,
  );

  Create table updated(
    updated_id int primary key auto_increment,
    updatedByEmployee CHAR(50),
    updatedFromOffice CHAR(50),
    updatedByCustumer CHAR(30),
    updatedDate dateTime,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would precede:

```
CREATE TABLE meta (
  meta_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  entity_type ENUM ('order', 'bill', 'etc') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'etc',
  entity_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  user_type ENUM('employee', 'customer') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'employee'
  user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no_name',
  office_id VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  action ENUM('create','update') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'create',
  dateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

so, an entry would look like

```
4, order, 50, employee, E10, head office, update, 2015-05-05 15:42:33
```

Which is translated to: "The employee with id (E10) updated the order of ID (50) on 2015-05-05 at 2015-05-05 from the head office"

What is good about this is that you can later add an extra field that describes the change, so you will have a tracking system :)

### Note please the following points:

- I assumed each entity table has an integer ID
- As mentioned before, you may want to avoid using `ENUM`
- `varchar` will save you some space.